# Firebase function not detected upon deploy after version bump

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Since a while we have setup our company's website in Firebase: we have setup the website in Angular, served through Firebase hosting, we use Firestore database for storing contacts from the contact form and we have also setup a firebase function written in TS (v1 it turns  out) to send and email to the interested parties every time we record a new entry in the contact form collection.

This has been working nicely up to now, but now I am tasked to extend our website with job application form. Kind of easy task, given what we have: I just need to replicate the logic of the general contact form in one more place. However, it turns out that I am having a problem with the firebase function deploy.

I tried using the old `package.json` and it produces a bunch of following errors when I try to build my functions:

```
npm --prefix ./functions run build

> build
> tsc

node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:99:68 - error TS1110: Type expected.
99 type RemoveTail<S extends string, Tail extends string> = S extends `${infer P}${Tail}` ? P : S;
                                                                      ~~~
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:99:77 - error TS1005: '}' expected.
99 type RemoveTail<S extends string, Tail extends string> = S extends `${infer P}${Tail}` ? P : S;
.......
../node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:1255:1 - error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.
1255 
     
Found 127 errors.
```

So this is a version problem, caused my used-to-be `package.json`, I am inlining it below:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/nodemailer-direct-transport": "^1.0.31",
    "@types/nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried fixing this with minor version fixes, but it did not work out at all. Thus I decided to just update everything to latest. This is my new `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "@types/nodemailer-direct-transport": "^1.0.32",
    "@types/nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

With this I was able to build functions, but when I try to deploy my functions just do not get detected. Even if I revert all my changes to `index.ts` when I get the following:

```
firebase deploy --project company-website --only functions:sendApplicationFormEmail

=== Deploying to 'company-website'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: current functions in project: sendContactFormEmail(europe-west3)
i  functions: uploading functions in project: sendContactFormEmail(europe-west3)

The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
    sendContactFormEmail(europe-west3)

If you are renaming a function or changing its region, it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one to prevent event loss. For more info, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify

? Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployments. No

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/company-website/overview
```

Note that this is my old used-to-exist function. Now, after the update it is not detected by the deploy engine at all. This is how I how I have defined the function:

// Sends an email every time a new data from the contact form is recorded

```
export const sendContactFormEmail = functions.region('europe-west3').firestore.document('contactPosts/{postId}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
```

Can anyone advise why my used-to-work function is not being detected anymore? Any migration necessary due to the version bump? Is it that I magically switched context to V2 functions? Or maybe google cloud functions come into play magically?

**EDIT**
After the suggestion from @RonnieRoyston I decided to experiment with really simple `index.ts`. I changed it to:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
 });
```

And then tried rebuilding:

```
npm --prefix ./functions run build
firebase deploy --project qualifast-com-website --only functions:helloWorld
```

This experiment passed successfully once, but from then on it is consistent in giving me the following error:

```
=== Deploying to 'company-website'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /my-local-path/functions (147.59 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 10 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    helloWorld(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Checking the cloud logs show (I tried both deleting the cloud function before the deploy attempt and not):

- `helloWorld - Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging`
- `Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.`

**EDIT 2**
Even in completely new project all functions fail deploying. Can someone please share working `package.json` that he is currently able to deploy?

Comment: I've always used: ```exports.sendContactFormEmail = pathtoFunctionIWantPublishedHere``` format in my index.js/index.ts file to get it to map properly. Can't hurt to try switching to something like that. That's how firebase's documentation suggests formatting it.

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope if the difference is `export const` vs `exports.` I tried that, no change.

Comment: Upvoted to hopefully get it more visibility. Sorry not of much help otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried (1) `firebase functions:delete sendContactFormEmail` then (2)  `firebase deploy --only functions:sendContactFormEmail`

Comment: @RonnieRoyston, sadly I both claim to be part of a company following good practices and processes and we never setup anything but prod environment for our website. This said, I dare not deleting the function and deploying again: there is a chance that the deployment would not succeed (both old version and new one) and then I have regressing functionality (contact form not working any more). I am glad to say that the contact form is used frequently and breaking it will have impact on my business. Is there a particular reason why you believe your suggestion might be the fix?

Comment: I guess we would really need to see the `index` file? Try adding a simple test function and see if it gets deployed...?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston I do not mind adding simplest function as a test, but what would that function be? Do you think you can advise? The reason why I did not share the index.ts is mostly because it is quite lengthy and I am trying to spare spurious details in either way too detail rich question

Comment: `exports.foo = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // ...
});` would be a simple function that does nothing

Comment: Are you deploying a lot of functions at once? I would consider trying to deploy only that function if you are trying to update it and see if that works by itself.

Comment: @AlexanderN. I tried deploying both only the old and the new functions. Both not detected. Ronnie, I will experiment with simpler function tomorrow when I get to my desk

Comment: @RonnieRoyston as promised I am giving update on my struggles. I used the most basic example function and it did deploy ok. After that I started figuring some things that are problematic in my code. I was using `console.log` that used to work ok, but seem to be causing problem now: I substituted with `functions.log` With this change my functions started being detected, but I now face problems in deployment, I will try to resolve them now

Comment: @RonnieRoyston I updated my question with details of my experiments. Somehow, after a single deploy success (over a simple function) I get consistent deploy errors

Comment: @RonnieRoyston I tried setting up completely new project. I still get failures for deployment of whatever function. Do you think you can share a currently working `package.json` for firebase functions?

Comment: I think you need to look at the logs to see what Node.js is throwing.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston basically I already included all the errors I am getting. Complicated stacktrace, but it tells you nothing but "I failed to start"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much struggles, I was eventually forced to setup a second environment and trace down all problems in the code.

The main thing is that apparently Firebase functions are not able to deploy successfully functions v1 with Node 10 anymore. This is never explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but this is what I saw. When I switched my `package.json` to use:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
```

I finally got stable deployment. Regretfully, one is not able to deploy functions with different engines, but once I setup a test environment, I was able to make sure everything will work ok and just then I went to my prod website and removed my existing function. With this, i was able to deploy both the old and new functions with the new engine.